# Which goalkeepers rush out in EA FC Mobile 24?

Tags: ea-sports-fc-mobile

I see some goalkeepers rush out to save shorts more than others while playing vs attack or manager mode. which players does it? I brought 90 neuer and made him 95 and upgraded his sweeper keeper skill, but see pope, onana is more sweeping or rushing out.